# Linking gnustl into Android ndk project with stlport_static

Tags: android, c++11, android-ndk, shared-libraries, stlport

In my Android.mk and Application.mk , I am using a static library which is build using `stlpot_static`, but I want to use gnustl instead of stlport to build my project because I need support of c++11 in my project.
Earlier I was using `APP_STL := stlport_shared` Application.mk in my  and my project was running successfully.
But now I want to make it `APP_STL := gnustl_shared`, the project compiles successfully but it crashes during run time giving me a error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNSt13_Filebuf_base12_M_page_sizeE"`, when I checked for this error,I found this dependency in my static library which was build using stlport_static.

How can I use gnustl with my project without disturbing my static library which has its dependency on stlport_static.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix and match STLs in a single binary: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/user/common_problems.md#Using-Mismatched-Prebuilt-Libraries